# How to keep the small sidebar style when screen size change ?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I want to create a small side navbar for a mobile first web map.

I found a snippet of code that do what I want but when the page reduce to a specific width the navbar stick to the top then I lose the effect I want to create with the small sliding icons. I try to change the min-width in the media query it did change. Please do propose a Jquery approach, I like this simple html and css method.

This is the link for the Bootsnipp, I am working on : http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/pjyo4

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>      
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">Acceuil<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown"> 
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Utilisateur<span class="caret"></span>
                    <span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                    </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="{{URL::to('createusuario')}}">Créer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Modifier</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reporter</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lien séparé</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>     
                </ul>
                </li>        

            <li >
                <a href="#">Référence<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a>
            </li>        
            <li >
                <a href="#">Tags<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and this is my CSS3 :

```
body,html{
height: 100%;
}

nav.sidebar, .main{
-webkit-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
}

.main{
padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 765px) {

.main{
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 40px); 
  margin-left: 40px;
  float: right;
}

nav.sidebar:hover + .main{
  margin-left: 200px;
}

nav.sidebar.navbar.sidebar>.container .navbar-brand, .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

nav.sidebar .navbar-brand, nav.sidebar .navbar-header{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

nav.sidebar a{
  padding-right: 13px;
}

nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li:first-child{
  border-top: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
}

nav.sidebar .navbar-nav > li{
  border-bottom: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
}

nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

nav.sidebar .navbar-collapse, nav.sidebar .container-fluid{
  padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #777;
}

nav.sidebar{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -160px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

nav.sidebar li {
  width: 100%;
}

nav.sidebar:hover{
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.forAnimate{
  opacity: 0;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1330px) {

.main{
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  margin-left: 200px;
}

nav.sidebar{
  margin-left: 0px;
  float: left;
}

nav.sidebar .forAnimate{
  opacity: 1;
}
}

nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, nav.sidebar 
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #CCC;
background-color: transparent;
}

nav:hover .forAnimate{
 opacity: 1;
}
section{
 padding-left: 15px;
}
```

My goal is to keep the sidebar style with the small icons that show when mouse over the side bar.

Comment: Always try to write your code in https://jsfiddle.net/ instead of writing huge code here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you want that the menu stays at the left side all the time and doesn't switch to the mobile dropdown at the top.
If you delete the part which displays the dropdown:

```
<div class="container-fluid">       
                
    <div class="navbar-header">     
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">     
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>      
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>      
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>      
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>      
        </button>           
    </div>
 </div>
```

and additionally to that the media query in the css:

```
 @media (min-width: 765px) {
```

which limits the CSS at a screen width bigger than 765px.

Now you have your menu all the time at the left side.
The only problem is that the glyphicons and letters are hidden, and I don't know why.
Sadly I am not so familiar with bootstrap .. but I hope I could help you a little bit.